# __attribute__((packed)) alternative

Tags: c++, c, padding, packed

consider the following structure:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) a{
    int a1;
    int b2;
    char cArray[5];
    int c3;
} Mystruct;
```

Now in my code, Im doing this:

```
char source[50];
Mystruct mm;
//...
//initialization and other codes
//...
memcpy(&mm,source,sizeof(mm));
```

I am trying to fill up the structure from a string (from a file to be more specific), and hence I don't want the padding. But think packing affects the performance also.

So my question is, is there any other way to accomplish what I want?
Is it possible to do the same (filling up from a string) with member variables of a class in c++? If yes, how?

Comment: Please post the *actual* code, not an approximation of it.

Comment: sorry @PaulR, I can't post the actual code right now. however, the code above can explain my question.

Comment: I'd highly recommend you purchase and read [`Write Portable Code`](http://www.hookatooka.com/wpc/).  You don't want to take this approach.  Not only because it isn't portable (think endianess issues), but it does impact performance and atomicity (non-aligned 32-bit access is not atomic on x86 without a LOCK prefix).  It's much better to [marshal/unmarshal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)), even though it's a bit more work up front.

Comment: @jszakmeister, That should be an answer, IMO :)

Comment: @AnishRam Thanks for the nudge... I made it an answer now. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd highly recommend you purchase and read [Write Portable Code](http://www.hookatooka.com/wpc/). You don't want to take this approach. Not only because it isn't portable (think endianess issues), but it does impact performance and atomicity (non-aligned 32-bit access is not atomic on x86 without a LOCK prefix). It's much better to [marshal/unmarshal‌](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_%28computer_science%29)​, even though it's a bit more work up front.

The idea behind marshaling/unmarshaling is to convert your data from one format to another, and them back again.  This is what frameworks like [Google Protocol Buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), and many others do to transfer data in a portable way.  You basically have specialized functions that take your "string" data that you spoke of, and you parse it, *validate* it, and then assign it into your structure.  You'll see marshaling and serialization used interchangeably in many contexts.

For instance, in your case, you might have a function with the prototype:

```
int
unmarshal_mystruct(const char *data, MyStruct &m);
```

Internally, you'd parse the data from `data`, and populate `m`.  It does get tedious which is why so many people use the frameworks.

Comment: can you please elaborate a little on marshaling?

Answer (score 3):

Use serialization/deserialization code. I.e. read into byte array, for example, and then convert values into structure. This is how many frameworks do (i.e. CORBA etc).

Drawbacks: more code to write.

Benefits: better portability, compatibility between LE/BE platforms. For example, you code may not work on some ARM devices.

Example (struct):

```
typedef struct a
{
    int a1;
    int b2;
    char cArray[5];
    int c3;
} Mystruct;
```

Writing:

```
void write_int(FILE *f, int value)
{
    int32_t tmp = htonl(value); // write in BE form
    fwrite(&tmp, 4, 1, f);
}

void a_write(Mystruct *d, FILE *f)
{
    write_int(f, d->a1);
    write_int(f, d->b2);
    fwrite(d->cArray, 5, 1, f);
    write_int(f, d->c3);
}
```

Reading:

```
void read_int(FILE *f, int *value)
{
    int32_t tmp;
    fread(&tmp, 4, 1, f);
    *value = ntohl(tmp);
}

void a_read(Mystruct *d, FILE *f)
{
    read_int(f, &d->a1);
    read_int(f, &d->b2);
    fread(d->cArray, 5, 1, f);
    read_int(f, &d->c3);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Valeri-Atamaniouk, I understood the concept. One thing, in `read_int` shouldn't it be `*value = ntohl(tmp)`?

Comment: I would suggest not using magic numbers. Why not use `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(d->cArray)` instead?

Comment: @AnishRam When dealing with files, you deal not so much with data mapping, but rather with file structure. Technically my code is wrong, as it make assumption that `int32_t` always maps to 4 bytes, which might not be the case. Better alternative is to read data to byte array, and after that assemble the value.